# Implement trait for slice with lifetime bound from function parameter

Tags: rust, traits, borrow-checker

In the following snippet, I'm trying to implement *C*:

```rust
// A
trait Get {
    fn get(slice: &[f32]) -> Self;
}

// B
impl Get for () {
    fn get(slice: &[f32]) -> Self {
        ()
    }
}

// C
impl Get for &[f32] {
    fn get(slice: &[f32]) -> Self {
        &slice[0..5]
    }
}
```

This doesn't work however, because the borrow-checker (rightfully) complains that the lifetime for the outer `&[f32]` doesn't match with the lifetime of `slice`. How do I express this, preferably without changing the trait?

I've tried the following, but without result:

```rust
// Doesn't work because the function signature differs from the Trait
impl<'a> Get for &'a [f32] {
    fn get(slice: &'a [f32]) -> Self {
        &slice[0..5]
    }
}

// Doesn't work, because the trait bound is not the same as the trait function
impl<'b> Get for &'b [f32] {
    fn get<'a>(slice: &'a [f32]) -> Self where 'a: 'b {
        &slice[0..5]
    }
}
```

Comment: It cannot be done without changing the trait. As written, `Get` means you can get `Self` out of a reference to `[f32]` of any lifetime; that simply isn't possible for `Self` with a longer lifetime. If this is what `Get` means then you just cannot implement it for `&[f32]`, similar to how you can't implement `AsRef<f64>` for `f32`; the type just doesn't support such a thing.

Comment: Just for my understanding, but aren’t I also implementing for &[f32] of any lifetime in _C_? It’s more that there is no way to tie the unknown two lifetimes together without adjusting the trait, right?

Comment: Kind of? Those are two different "any" lifetimes. There's no constraint you can put on *any `'b`* in `&'b [f32]` that would make it "small enough" to be smaller than *any `'a`* in `&'a [f32]`. This isn't a limitation of Rust not having the right syntax to express something; it's a violation of what `Get` *means* to implement it for a slice reference.

Comment: Alright, I understand then. That’s what I tried to say, but you managed to put it way better :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about making `Get` generic over the lifetime `'a`:

```
trait Get<'a> {
    fn get(slice: &'a [f32]) -> Self;
}

impl<'a> Get<'a> for () {
    fn get(slice: &'a [f32]) -> Self {
        ()
    }
}

impl<'a> Get<'a> for &'a [f32] {
    fn get(slice: &'a [f32]) -> Self {
        &slice[0..5]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, ideally looking for a way to not change the trait, but I suspect that’s impossible.